# Constructing const object vs reference to const object

Tags: c++, reference, constants

I'm curious regarding best practices. Let's assume I need to construct an object that further is not supposed to be modified:

```
  void fn() {
    const std::string& ref_to_const = "one";
    ...
    const std::string const_object = "two";
    ...
  }
```

The lifespan of both temporary object and const object will be the same. So what approach to use?

Comment: Which one of them is a temporary object, and which one is a const object? As for me both of them are temporary and const.

Comment: In my opinion, references are mostly useful when working with functions. Additionally, I might consider using a const reference to an existing mutable object to indicate, that in some part of the code, I would not modify this object (which might, maybe, allow a compiler to apply more aggressive optimizations and avoid attempts to modify this object where this shouldn't happen). I don't see any reason why use a const reference your way to bind to a temporary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> So what approach to use?

Generally, the one that is more expressive: the plain `const std::string`.

The fact that a constant reference can bind to and extend the lifetime of a temporary value mainly exists for making call-by-reference possible for temporaries. There is no reason to make use of this in a situation like yours.

Answer (score 3):

You create an instance, and using a reference to store that instance is just obfuscating this fact. Make your code explicit: You create an instance, so declare it as an instance, not as a reference:

```
const std::string const_object = "two";
```